# Australian and US Passport - Travel to Ukraine from Germany

Tags: visas, us-citizens, dual-nationality, australian-citizens

I flew into Germany in November 2018 and then applied for a working Holiday Visa in germany. I have this by now (a card saying Aufenthaltstitel/residence permit, valid until november 2019) and I would like to visit Ukraine now.. US citizens do not need a visa to get into Ukraine, but Australians do.. Can I use my US passport to fly to Ukraine now or do I have to get a visa and use my Australian one?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your Australian passport to clear Schengen emigration, enter Ukraine on your US passport. Leave Ukraine on your US passport, enter Germany on your Australian passport.

Show your US passport to check in/ticket checking staff as this is proof you can go to Ukraine visa free.

Comment: Is it legal or can I get in trouble?

Comment: 100% legal, you're a US citizen, a pro of having dual nationality.

Comment: +1, I am a dual Aussie and Italian, and Italians can enter visa free. Used my Italian passport to enter Ukraine and there were no issues whatsoever.